# group_concat function removing duplicates

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

Created the below query in BigQuery:

```
SELECT
  date,
  userId,
  SUM(totals.visits) totalvisits,
  GROUP_CONCAT(device.deviceCategory) sequentialdevice
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    visitStartTime,
    customDimensions.value userId,
    totals.visits,
    device.deviceCategory
  FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([164345793.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('20171127'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
  WHERE
    customDimensions.index = 1
    AND customDimensions.value CONTAINS "hip|"
  GROUP BY
    date,
    visitStartTime,
    userId,
    totals.visits,
    device.deviceCategory
  HAVING
    userId="hip|7e4fbce9-bbfb-4677-aab0-dcd02851fdb4"
  ORDER BY
    date ASC,
    visitStartTime ASC)
GROUP BY
  date,
  userId
```

As a temp measure I'm using the having clause to test it out (this will be removed in production) The query outputs the following:

[image]

This is all great and works as expected, outputting the devices in the appropriate order (tablet,tablet,tablet,mobile,desktop) - however, I want to remove duplicates from this, so the results would be "tablet,mobile,desktop"

I tried to use the Unique() function, this removes the duplicates, however, the order is not retained, so the output becomes "desktop,mobile,tablet"

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update**

I updated the query to Standard SQL and now I'm facing another issue using the string_agg() function:

```
SELECT
  date,
  userId,
  totalsvisits,
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT devicecategory ORDER BY date ASC, vstime ASC) deviceAgg
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    visitStartTime vstime,
    cd.value userId,
    totals.visits totalsvisits,
    device.deviceCategory devicecategory
  FROM
    `12314124123123.ga_sessions_*`,
    UNNEST(customDimensions) AS cd
  WHERE
    cd.index=1
    AND cd.value IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY
    date,
    visitStartTime,
    userId,
    totals.visits,
    device.deviceCategory
  HAVING
    userId="hip|7e4fbce9-bbfb-4677-aab0-dcd02851fdb4"
  ORDER BY
    date ASC,
    visitStartTime ASC)
GROUP BY
  date,
  userId,
  totalsvisits
```

The error returned is "An aggregate function that has both DISTINCT and ORDER BY arguments can only ORDER BY columns that are arguments to the function"

Obviously, if we remove distinct or order by clause from string_agg, this works, but we need both operations.

Comment: Time to update to Standard SQL.  You can use `STRING_AGG(DISTINCT)`.

Comment: Tried using "GROUP_CONCAT(distinct device.deviceCategory)" I get the error message "DISTINCT can only be used inside COUNT aggregation or analytic function"

Comment: As Gordon said, you need to use `STRING_AGG` using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql). `GROUP_CONCAT` is specific to legacy SQL in BigQuery.

Comment: See updated post, I've converted to standard sql, facing a new issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the updated question, the following query produces the same error:

```
SELECT age_midpoint, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT country ORDER BY c DESC)
FROM (
  SELECT country, age_midpoint, COUNT(*) c
  FROM `fh-bigquery.stackoverflow.survey_results_2016`
  WHERE age_midpoint IS NOT null
  AND country LIKE '%u%'
  GROUP BY 1, 2
)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

The limitation makes sense, because once you run `DISTINCT`, you lose visibility into the variable you wanted to provide the order.

Try this instead:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT age_midpoint, ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(
  SELECT country FROM (SELECT country, c FROM UNNEST(arr) GROUP BY country, c) ORDER BY c DESC
), ',')
FROM (
  SELECT age_midpoint, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(country, c)) arr
  FROM (
    SELECT country, age_midpoint, COUNT(*) c
    FROM `fh-bigquery.stackoverflow.survey_results_2016`
    WHERE age_midpoint IS NOT null
    AND country LIKE '%u%'
    GROUP BY 1, 2
  )
  GROUP BY 1
)
ORDER BY 1
LIMIT 1000
```

(See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#creating-arrays-from-subqueries)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, managed to take the concept and apply to the query, and it's now sequential!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Felipe on this, here's the completed query!

```
SELECT
date, value, SUM(visits) visits, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT seqdevice) seqdevice, COUNT(DISTINCT seqdevice) countseqdevice
FROM (
SELECT date, value, visits, ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(
  SELECT deviceCategory FROM (SELECT deviceCategory, c FROM UNNEST(arr) GROUP BY deviceCategory, c) ORDER BY c DESC
), ',') seqdevice
FROM (
SELECT date, visitStartTime, value, visits, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(deviceCategory, c)) arr
FROM (
    SELECT date, visitStartTime, cd.value value, totals.visits visits, device.deviceCategory deviceCategory, COUNT(*) c
    FROM `xxxxxxxxxx`, UNNEST(customDimensions) AS cd
    WHERE cd.index=1 AND STARTS_WITH(cd.value,"hip|")
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    )
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
)
ORDER BY 2)
 GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING
  value="hip|7e4fbce9-bbfb-4677-aab0-dcd02851fdb4"

ORDER BY countseqdevice desc
```